# How to remove sale prices from items that have no catalog price rules or special prices.

Tags: price, sales

I am trying to remove a sale price from 4 products in magento. There has been no catalog price rules or special prices added for these products yet they are appearing on the website as sale items. What could be the cause of this and how can i remove the sale price for these items?

Comment: check is there any tier prices added ? also do reindex from System > Index management.....

Comment: no tier prices have been added and everything in the index management section is up to date so still not sure what it could be.

Comment: can you change store view and check in particular stores..... may be special price is set under store.....